# Batch command mixing syntax during execution

Tags: batch-file

I have tried to add a variable into an already existing batch file that I have written.  However, when using the new command with the variable the command gets jumbled up.

How it supposed to work.
A user is prompted for an input (one of 3 letters).  The input dictates the root directory used for a software execution.  This section of code pulls a list of .elf files and is supposed to write them to a .txt file in the root directory.

Issue.
When using the variable directory, the .txt file and directory are switched during execution.

Original (Works)

```
DIR \\somepath\%VAR%\*.elf /b /o-s>C:\MyRootFolder\unlk.txt
```

New command with 2nd variable (acts strangely)

```
DIR \\somepath\%VAR%\*.elf /b /o-s>%root%\unlk.txt
```

but executes like this!?

```
DIR \\somepath\25091562033-00\*.elf /b /o-s \unlk.txt 1>C:\MyRootFolder
```

I am trying to have my root folder selected by an input further up because there are 3 different versions of software that I need to use to perform an operation.   Being able to have the folder selected by an input would make things a lot easier.

Any ideas of why this executes semi-backwards?

Edit:

Here is the first section of my batch file all the way down to where the error happens.  I have removed some of the code that doesn't relate to the issue.  Note that the excessive pauses are for troubleshooting and the section which sets the variable %ECUPN% has been removed as it is working as intended.

```
ECHO off
:Ask
CLS
ECHO What type of processor does this ECU have?
ECHO F = Freescale_Quasar
ECHO T = TI
ECHO M = Motorola
SET INPUT=
SET /P INPUT=[F/T/M]: %=%
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="F" SET root=C:\Freescale_Quasar && GOTO :Fetch
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="T" SET root=C:\TI_MK100 && GOTO :Fetch
IF /I "%INPUT%"=="M" SET root=C:\MK100_Motorola && GOTO :Fetch
GOTO :Ask

:Fetch
CLS
Echo on
ECHO Fetch
pause
DIR \\mofs01p2.auto.contiwan.com\didf5076\FlashDataFiles\Flashline\%ECUPN%\*.elf /b /o-s>%root%\unlk.txt
pause
SET /P Code=<%root%\unlk.txt
pause
COPY "\\mofs01p2.auto.contiwan.com\didf5076\FlashDataFiles\Flashline\%ECUPN%\%Code%" "%root%\unlock.elf" || GOTO :error_1
pause
ECHO App  = %code%>>C:\Unlock\log.txt
pause
GOTO :Build_1
```

Comment: You need to provide all the code that is affecting your problem.

Comment: To begin with, I'd suggest using the following syntax, `Dir /B/O-S "\\somepath\%VAR%\*.elf">"%root%\unlk.txt"` I would also strongly suggest that if you're accepting input for one or more of the variables, `%var%` and `%root%` that you've included a robust system of verifying their content matches that which is accepted in the commands you're running.

Comment: I'd bet variable `root` contains `C:\MyRootFolder` + _space_... To avoid that use the quoted syntax `set "root=C:\MyRootFolder"`, so trailing spaces do not become part of the value, neither do the quotes...

Comment: Best practice for using the set command is too surround the command within quotes. `SET "root=C:\Freescale_Quasar"`

Comment: Thanks guys.  The quotes worked to fix it.